# How does conservation of angular momentum work in electric dipole transitions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

The selection rules for an electric dipole ($\textrm E_1$) transition give $\Delta J = 0,\pm 1$, $\Delta M_j = 0,\pm 1$. However, a dipole transition corresponds to the emission of a photon with total intrinsic angular momentum of $1$ and $M_s\pm 1$.
In the L-S basis the selection rules will become more specific and only allow $\Delta L = \pm 1$.

How can an electron keep $m_s$ and $m_l$ the same but still emit a photon, given that the photon has $m_s$ non zero?

Comment: In the Wigner-Eckart theorem the dipole operator relevant to this transition has three allowed states (m = 0, 1, -1). How does this relate to the intrinsic spin of a photon, i.e. the thing that mediates the transition?